# Unsupported correlated query redshift for case when exists

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

I'm running a `case when exists` to try to filter out anamoly data from my table, but I am running into a `unsupported correlated query` error.

I have a table of anomalies for different metrics and I want to null those metric values out in my final results if they're in this anomaly table.

I have a table, `anomalytable`, which stores an id, the metric type of the anomaly, and the date range which this occurs.

```
| id   | startdate | enddate | metrictype |
| ---- | --------- | ------- | -----------|
| 1    | 1/1/23    | 1/3/23  | metric1    |
| 2    | 1/3/23    | 1/5/23  | metric2    |
```

I have a results table where I want to null the metrics for if they belong in the above table.

```
| id   | metric1   | metric2 |  date  |
| ---- | --------- | ------- | -------|
| 1    | 300       | 1.2     | 1/2/23 |
| 2    | 1.1       | 500     | 1/4/23 |
```

What I'm hoping my final results will look like (as you can see, the 300 and 500 anomaly numbers were nulled out)

```
| id   | metric1   | metric2 | date   |
| ---- | --------- | ------- | -------|
| 1    | null      | 1.2     | 1/2/23 |
| 2    | 1.1       | null    | 1/4/23 |
```

My query is below

```
select 
case when exists 
   (select * from anomalytable b where a.id = b.id and a.date between b.startdate and b.enddate and b.metricname = 'metric1') 
then null else a.metric1 end, 
case when exists 
   (select * from anomalytable b where a.id = b.id and a.date between b.startdate and b.enddate and b.metricname = 'metric2') 
then null else a.metric2 end
from resultstable a
```

However everytime I run this I get the `correlated subquery pattern not supported` error. I've read through the redshift unsupported correlated queries and can't see what rule I'm breaking. Is it possible to rewrite this with joins in a clean fashion?

Comment: Your schema does not match your query. metricname? metric1val? metric2val? And should it be `b.metricname = 'metric1'` (note the quotes)?

Comment: Ah sorry I edited to make it clearer but didn't change the query. Will change. But yes your interpretation is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join instead. Simpler and likely faster.

```
select
  r.id,
  case when a.metricname = 'metric1' then null else r.metric1val end,
  case when a.metricname = 'metric2' then null else r.metric2val end,
  r.date
from resultstable r
left join anomalytable a on r.id = a.id and r.date between a.startdate and a.enddate
```

Comment: Ah cool! Used a variation of this join to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a correlated subquery due to the changing results of the subquery based on the row selected in the top query.  This is better done with a join - fewer table scans.

```
select a.id, 
   case when b.metrictype = 'metric1' then null
     else metric1 end metric1,
   case when b.metrictype = 'metric2' then null
     else metric2 end metric2,
   a."date"
from resultstable a
join anomalytable b
on a.id = b.id and a.date between b.startdate and b.enddate
;
```

Here's a fiddle to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e677c/6